# MYSQL - Optimizing MAX(CASE WHEN ...)

Tags: mysql, performance, aggregate, query-performance

I have a table similar to the following (**Updated**: added a `type` column** Simplified the real query too much I guess)

```
CREATE TABLE versions(
   type INT NOT NULL,
   version INT NOT NULL,
   important BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (type, version)
)
```

Running `SELECT type, MAX(version) FROM versions GROUP BY type` is very efficient and retrieves a single row per type from the database.

**However**, running `SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN important=1 THEN version END) FROM versions GROUP BY type` seems to generate a full table scan.

Since I have an index on version I expected MySQL to start scanning versions from the highest and stop when it finds the first that has "important=1". Usually, with my data this requires scanning just a few rows.

Looking at `performance_schema.events_statements_history` (`ROWS_EXAMINED` column) it seems like MySQL scans the entire table in order to retrieve the row I need.

Any ideas on how to improve the performance of this query will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the table InnoDB? What is the version of MySQL you use?

Comment: InnodB. MySQL 5.7.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple queries (without `GROUOP BY`), you can rewrite them as:

```
SELECT version 
FROM versions 
-- WHERE important = 1
ORDER BY version DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

and check if the execution plan does not do a table scan and using the index in the way that you expect.

Additionally, you can add an index on `(important, version)`.

---

For the `GROUP BY type` queries, an index on `(important, type, version)` would fit better.

Rewriting that query with `LIMIT 1` is not trivial as we want many maximum (one for each type). But if the index alone doesn't improve things much, here is a different query that will use the above composite index.

Performance is usually improved with this method when there are few distinct type values:

```
SELECT dt.type, v.version 
FROM 
    ( SELECT type 
      FROM versions 
      WHERE important = 1
      GROUP BY type
    ) AS dt
  -- LEFT
  JOIN versions AS v
  ON  v.important = 1
  AND v.type = dt.type 
  AND v.version = ( SELECT vi.version
                    FROM versions AS vi
                    WHERE vi.important = 1
                      AND vi.type = dt.type
                    ORDER BY vi.version DESC
                    LIMIT 1 
                  ) ;
```

There are variations you could try. For example, removing the `important = 1`  (only from inside the derived table `dt`) and using `LEFT JOIN` there. This would give you all types (and NULL values for the types that have no version marked as "important".

If you have a separate table, with all the types (i.e. `PRIMARY KEY (type)`), you could completely replace the `dt` with that table.

Comment: OK. That was simple. The actual query involves a `GROUP BY` clause and the above max is need per group. It is possible to extend this solution?

Comment: Well, if the actual query is different and we know nothing about it, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the question. Was trying to simplify the problem to the bare essentials. Too much simplification in this case. And the index does help. I was using an index on `(version, important)` and the order makes a difference here. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT type, MAX(version)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE important = 1;

INDEX(important, type, version)
```

Many optimizations (including the first one you mentioned) do not "come for free", but must be added if they are deemed "worth the effort".  I do *not* know whether the `SELECT` and `INDEX` I just presented is covered by the optimization.  Try it.

Notes:

- It is "covering" since all the columns in the `SELECT` are in the one index.  (Can it be covering for your un-simplified version?)
- Within the part of the index where `important=1`, the use of `type` and `version` work just like the original optimization.  But is the Optimizer smart enough to notice it?
- This `INDEX` should not be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Thanks. Reordering the fields in the index so that `important` comes first helped. Can you explain why the index should not be the primary key?

Comment: @nimrodm - Currently the PK says that type+version is "unique".  Adding another column (`important`) to the PK would allow multiple rows for a given type+version -- probably not what you want.